# remove _id attribute from a mongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

_id attribute is automatically inserted when inserting data. According to documentation, _id ensures uniqueness for data. The thing is, I already have another key that ensures uniqueness for me. Hence I don't require _id anymore. How can I remove it from every record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove `_id`, MongoDB needs it. But you may write your unique key into `_id`.